# Deserializing ISODate objects from MongoDB into Java POJO

Tags: java, mongodb

I have existing data in MongoDB formatted as such:

```
"created_at" : ISODate("2011-11-25T18:17:16Z")
```

When I try to deserialize into java POJO using morphia, it gives the date as system timezone applied date instead of GMT date.

```
/**
 * The Class AggregationQueryDetails.
 */
public class AggregationQueryResultTriggeredPolicyDetails {

    /** The triggered time. */
    private Date created_at;

    /** The event ids. */
    private List<String> event_ids;


    /**
     * @return the CreatedAt
     */
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return created_at;
    }

    /**
     * @param CreatedAt
     *            the CreatedAt to set
     */
    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.created_at = createdAt;
    }
}
```

How can i avoid timezone conversion ?

Comment: Can you add the relevant code and your pojo class ? What is your java and morphia version ? How did you verify the date is in your local time zone ?

Comment: Added pojo class. getCreatedAt method gives the converted to local time value instead of actual time. This is observed while debugging my code.

Comment: That is expected behavior as mentioned in answer. The internal time value saved in Date is a UTC value. So you should be fine. If you are on java 8 you should use java.time.Instant.

Comment: `java.time.Instant.parse( "2011-11-25T18:17:16Z" )`

Answer (score 0):

Internally a java.util.Date does not store timezone. The date is internally represented in UTC. It is up to you to format the date into the timezone that you wish.

The behavior that you are most likely seeing is due to the fact that when you "view" a java.util.Date either in a debugger or by printing it, it will be shown in the local timezone.

Here's a very basic example of how to format:

```
public static String ISO_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz";
private static final TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
private static final SimpleDateFormat isoFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_FORMAT);
static {
    isoFormatter.setTimeZone(utc);
}
...

public String toString() {
    return "myDate: " + isoFormatter.format(myDate);
}
```